# Implement a TimeWindowBuffer of limited size

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, timeout, buffer

I'd an interview yesterday. I couldn't figure out a solution to one programming problem and I'd like to get some ideas here. The problem is:

I need to implement a *TimeWindowBuffer* in Java, which stores the number a user continuously receives  as time goes on. The buffer has a *maxBufferSize*. The user wants to know the average value of the past several seconds, a *timeWindow* passed in by user (so this is a sliding window). We could get the current time from the system (e.g. `System.currentTimeMills()` in Java). The *TimeWindowBuffer* class is like this:

```
public class TimeWindowBuffer {
  private int maxBufferSize;
  private int timeWindow;

  public TimwWindowBuffer(int maxBufferSize, int timeWindow) {
     this.maxBufferSize = maxBufferSize;
     this.timeWindow = timeWindow;
  }

  public void addValue(long value) {
     ...
  }

  public double getAvg() {
     ...
     return average;
  }

  // other auxiliary methods
}
```

Example:

Say, a user receive a number every second (the user may not receive a number at a certain rate) and wants to know **the average value of the past 5 seconds**.
**Input**:
maxBufferSize = 5, timeWindow = 5 (s)
numbers={-5 4 -8 -8 -8 1 6 1 8 5}
**Output** (I list the formula here for illustration but the user only needs the result)
:
-5 / 1 (t=1)
(-5 + 4) / 2 (t=2)
(-5 + 4 - 8) / 3 (t=3)
(-5 + 4 - 8 - 8) / 4 (t=4)
(-5 + 4 - 8 - 8 - 8) / 5 (t=5)
(4 - 8 - 8 - 8 + 1) / 5 (t=6)
(-8 - 8 - 8 + 1 + 6) / 5 (t=7)
(-8 - 8 + 1 + 6 + 1) / 5 (t=8)
(-8 + 1 + 6 + 1 + 8) / 5 (t=9)
(1 + 6 + 1 + 8 + 5) / 5 (t=10)

Since the data structure of the *TimeWindowBuffer* is not specified, I've been thinking about keeping a pair of value and its added time. So my declaration of underlying buffer is like this:

```
 private ArrayList<Pair> buffer = new ArrayList<Pair>(maxBufferSize);
```

where

```
class Pair {
  private long value;
  private long time;
  ...
}
```

Since the Pair is added in time order, I could do a binary search on the list and calculate the average of the numbers that fall into the *timeWindow*. The problem is the buffer has a *maxBufferSize* (although ArrayList doesn't) and I have to remove the oldest value when the buffer is full. And that value could still satisfy the *timeWindow* but now it goes off the record and I will never know when it expires.

I'm stuck here for the current.

I don't need a direct answer but have some discussion or ideas here. Please let me now if there are any confusions about the problem and my description.

Comment: please let me know why you think the question is inappropriate or something. A down vote without explanation won't help me to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy little puzzles like this.  I did not compile this code, nor did I take into account all the things you would have to for production usage.  Like I did not design a way to set a missed value to 0 - i.e. if a value does not come in at every tick.

But this will give you another way to think of it....

```
public class TickTimer
{
  private int tick = 0;
  private java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

  public TickTimer(double timeWindow)
  {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TickerTask(),
          0, // initial delay
          Math.round(1000/timeWindow)); // interval
  }

  private class TickerTask extends TimerTask
  {
    public void run ()
    {
      tick++;
    }
  }

  public int getTicks()
  {
    return tick;
  }
}

public class TimeWindowBuffer
{
  int buffer[];
  TickTimer timer;

  final Object bufferSync = new Object();

  public TimeWindowBuffer(int maxBufferSize, double timeWindow)
  {
    buffer = new int[maxBufferSize]; 
    timer = TickTimer(timeWindow);
  }

  public boolean add(int value)
  {
    synchronize(bufferSync)
    {
      buffer[timer.getTicks() % maxBufferSize] = value;
    }
  }

  public int averageValue()
  {
    int average = 0;

    synchronize(bufferSync)
    {
      for (int i: buffer)
      {
        average += i;
      }
    }

    return average/maxBufferSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is an elegant solution, the one I should've thought of during the interview. Although I have to sacrifice some accuracy if the record get overwritten hasn't expired. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be summarized as using constant memory to compute some statistics on a stream.

To me it's a heap (priority queue) with `time` as the key  and `value` as the value, and least `time` on the top.

When you receive a new `(time,value)`, add it to the heap. If the heap size is greater than the buffer size, just remove the root node in the heap, until the heap is small enough.

Also by using a heap you can get the minimum `time` in the buffer (i.e. the heap) in O(1) time, so just remove the root (the node with the minimum `time`) until all out-dated pairs are cleared.

For statistics, keep an integer `sum`. When you add a new pair to the heap, `sum = sum + value of pair`. When you remove the root from the heap, `sum = sum - value of root`.

Comment: what if the pair I remove hasn't expired?

Comment: @manuzhang Don't you have to remove the oldest value when the buffer is full?

Comment: yes I do. But if the window is large enough then that value could still fall into the window when getting removed.

Comment: @manuzhang I don't understand. I think there are two conditions for removing, (1) buffer size, (2) time. As long as the buffer size is within limit, and out-dated values are removed, it's correct right?

Comment: I mean you remove a non-out-dated value because of the buffer size limit

Comment: @manuzhang Oh I see. But I suppose that's impossible if the the buffer is very small. After all you cannot store all that much information, e.g. for a whole year, in a buffer of length 1.

Comment: In that case, I think jco.owens's solution is simple and strong